# Mysterious string behavior in Javascript

Tags: node.js, string, unicode, next.js

```
let host = req.headers.host
console.log(host)
```

Prints `localhost:3000`. So far so good.

```
console.log(host === "localhost:3000")
```

Prints `false`. Uh?

```
console.log(host.length)
console.log("localhost:3000".length)
```

Prints `15` and `14`. Our mystery string is one character longer? Let's look at each character one by one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < host.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, host.charAt(i));
}
```

Prints:

```
0 l
1 o
2 c
3 a
4 l
5 h
6 o
7 s
8 t
9 :
10 6
11 0
12 6
13 4
14 3
```

Printing one character at a time reveals that there are now 5 digits after the colon: `60643`. *Whaaat?*

This result changes every time I restart my web server. For example, last run it was `63275` and the previous run was `54313`.

Adding `console.log(host)` immediately after the for loop confirms **the string is still `localhost:3000`**. What's going on here?

I almost feel crazy asking this question, but I've looked at it all day and this happens 100% of the time. Environment: latest version of Node (`v17.3.0`), macOS Monterey (M1 mac).

---

### Followups

- **[Reproducible example here](https://github.com/DavidChouinard/string-issue-reproduction)** (requires a free [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) account)
- `typeof host` returns `string`
- Here's additional debugging information for each character of the
  string:

| `i` | `charAt(i)` | `charCodeAt(i)` | `codePointAt(i).toString(16)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | l | 108 | 6c |
| 1 | o | 111 | 6f |
| 2 | c | 99 | 63 |
| 3 | a | 97 | 61 |
| 4 | l | 108 | 6c |
| 5 | h | 104 | 68 |
| 6 | o | 111 | 6f |
| 7 | s | 115 | 73 |
| 8 | t | 116 | 74 |
| 9 | : | 58 | 3a |
| 10 | 5 | 53 | 35 |
| 11 | 4 | 52 | 34 |
| 12 | 8 | 56 | 38 |
| 13 | 6 | 54 | 36 |
| 14 | 2 | 50 | 32 |

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: Could you also log host.charCodeAt(i) in your loop? Just to make sure it's not some weird Unicode thing.

Comment: @Nils updated my question to add `charCodeAt` and `codePointAt`

Comment: Wow, this really is weird. No idea just from looking at the char codes. Are you able to provide the example with reasonable effort?

Comment: are you sure that `host` is the correct one?

Comment: @Nils It's been really puzzling. Here's a reproducible example: https://github.com/DavidChouinard/string-issue-reproduction

Comment: For security reasons, some headers can only be controlled by the user agent. These headers include the forbidden header names  and forbidden response header names. `Host` is the forbidden header name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers

Comment: The fact that `console.log(host === "localhost:3000")` prints `false` indicates that `host` is not a string.

Comment: @Kokodoko `typeof host` returns `string`

Comment: @DavidChouinard I have cloned your repo and cannot reproduce the behaviour you described. Did you try running this in the debugger (I suppose you're using VSCode)?

Comment: @Nils Uh. Appreciate you trying it. I'm running it in the console (no VS Code). What OS are you on? (and are you on Node 16 or 17?)

Comment: @DavidChouinard I'm running Node 16.13.0 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/cli#commands/dev):

> The **vercel dev** command is used to replicate the Vercel deployment
> environment locally, allowing you to test your Serverless Functions,
> without requiring you to deploy each time a change is made.

For this reason, calls like `/api/hello` are processed by local proxy server running with a random free port.

And here the most [interesting thing begins](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/blob/475a227ba90ffbf2356bd2dae1d17583c029da16/packages/cli/src/util/dev/server.ts#L2187): for the standard output (stdout) of the proxy server (and of course for the `console.log` too), the proxy port is replaced with the development port (it feels like it's an outdated legacy):

```
p.stdout.on('data', (data: string) => {
  process.stdout.write(data.replace(proxyPort, devPort));
});
```

For this reason, there is a difference in the length of the `req.headers.host` and `localhost:3000`, and why they look the same in the `console.log`, but are not equal when compared.

So it's better for example to use `x-forwarded-host` header instead of `host`:

```
console.log((
  req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] || req.headers.host
) === "localhost:3000");
res.status(200).json(req.headers);
```

Comment: Wow, good catch :D

Comment: Woah, great explanation! Thank you.